# How can we Re-write the Source Code of the website

Tags: php, regex

I would like to discuss with you about our requirement, like we have a program that get the source code of the website. we just want to insert the with some php function. Please look at the code below.

```
 <?php 
$url = "http://www.xyz.com" ;
function status($url){
//// here we check the particular url in our database and return the value.
}
$source = file_get_contents($url);
$insert = "<div id='status'>".status($url)."</div>" ;

?>
```

if the source code for the particular url is mentioned below.

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
    <div>
    <p>please look at the URL is <a href="http://www.abc.com">Good Example</a>.</p>
 </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

after the implemention of the function the source code should be like this. (please look at below.)

```
  <html>
 <head>
 </head>
  <body>
   <div>
  <p>please look at the URL is <a href="http://www.abc.com">Good Example</a><div id="status">Checked URL</div>.</p>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Conclusion** :- we have to check the every url of the source code (only in body tag). reform the source code with our implemented function called **status()** ;

I m beginner to complete this task.

Thanks 
PP

Comment: you could use regular expressions to make the change.

Comment: how can we make the regex script. for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class that allows manipulation of HTML

Comment: Is there any easy and fast way to achieve this goal ?

Comment: No.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Reading about it will be the easies and fastest way to achieve this goal. As a rule you shouldn't use regex to manipulate HTML, due to it's complexity, that's where DOMDocument comes in

Comment: Ok Kasia, Thanks for you giving time. :)